# Spring boot environment specific properties for dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-profiles

I am curious what is the best practice for environment (or even server) specific properties for dependencies.

This is not for properties that are managed by the applicationContext, as I am aware of the {env}-application.properties convention that Spring supports.

I will give a small example to elaborate:

My project, is project A. In A, we depend on Project B

A's pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.B</groupId>
     <artifactId>B</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Artifact B has a dependency on B.properties, which it does not provide and it must be on the classpath. I am unable to refactor Artifact B.

Contents of B.properties are:

```
b.someproperty=${property.placeholder}/b/dir
```

Contents of application.properties:

```
property.placeholder=default
```

Contents of dev-application.properties:

```
property.placeholder=dev
```

So when I run my spring boot app with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev, b.someproperty must resolve to dev/b/dir

What I have tried so far (that worked):

1) Externalized properties that sit on the server, with the placeholders already resolve and simply adding them to the classpath at runtime (So each server would have it's own B.properties file with no placeholders, and this would not be part of the build/deploy process)

2) Class within the spring bootable jar which takes the properties in b.properties, resolves all the placeholders, and writes it out to a file on the server and then adds this file to the classpath. So running the app with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev would generate b.properties on the server with no placeholders, and everything is contained within the jar.

Neither of these solutions are very clean, or good (imo). Is it possible to resolve the placeholders as the properties are being used, even if they are not being managed by the application context?

Any insight or criticism of my current solutions appreciated.